# Semantic-release - Error: Cannot find module '../output'

Tags: node.js, npm, bitbucket-pipelines, npx, semantic-release

No matter what I do I always get exactly the same error when I run command 'npx semantic-release --debug
' in BitBucket pipelines. Dry-run seems to run fine.

Thing I have already tried:

- reinstall node modules
- update packages
- copy exactly the same configuration/packages from    project with
  working semantic-release

All the files are definitely there. Maybe it can't access?

here is a full debug report:

```
npx: installed 746 in 16.856s
[5:36:26 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Running semantic-release version 17.1.1
2020-06-25T17:36:26.883Z semantic-release:config load config from: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/package.json
2020-06-25T17:36:26.887Z semantic-release:config options values: {
  branches: [ 'master', 'develop' ],
  repositoryUrl: 'git@$NEXUS_USERNAME.org:acurable/acupebble-g2-firmware.git',
  tagFormat: 'v${version}',
  plugins: [
    [ '@semantic-release/commit-analyzer', [Object] ],
    [ '@semantic-release/npm', [Object] ],
    [ '@semantic-release/release-notes-generator', [Object] ],
    '@semantic-release/changelog',
    '@semantic-release/git'
  ],
  _: [],
  debug: true,
  '$0': '/root/.npm/_npx/52/bin/semantic-release'
}
[5:36:27 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  An error occurred while running semantic-release: Error: Cannot find module '../output'
Require stack:
- /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/output-json.js
- /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/index.js
- /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js
- /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/@semantic-release/changelog/lib/prepare.js
- /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/@semantic-release/changelog/index.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/utils.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/index.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/get-config.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/bin/semantic-release.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:835:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1012:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/output-json.js:4:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1123:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:872:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1012:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/output-json.js',
    '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/index.js',
    '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js',
    '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/@semantic-release/changelog/lib/prepare.js',
    '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/@semantic-release/changelog/index.js',
    '/root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/utils.js',
    '/root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/index.js',
    '/root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/get-config.js',
    '/root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js',
    '/root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js',
    '/root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/bin/semantic-release.js'
  ]
}
Error: Cannot find module '../output'
Require stack:
- /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/output-json.js
- /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/index.js
- /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js
- /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/@semantic-release/changelog/lib/prepare.js
- /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/@semantic-release/changelog/index.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/utils.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/index.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/get-config.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/bin/semantic-release.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:835:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1012:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/output-json.js:4:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1123:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:872:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1012:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/output-json.js',
    '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/index.js',
    '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js',
    '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/@semantic-release/changelog/lib/prepare.js',
    '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/@semantic-release/changelog/index.js',
    '/root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/utils.js',
    '/root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/index.js',
    '/root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/get-config.js',
    '/root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js',
    '/root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js',
    '/root/.npm/_npx/52/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/bin/semantic-release.js'
  ]
2020-06-25T17:36:27.964997083Z stderr P }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is crazy.

Just realised that I had this line in gitIgnore.txt: **/Output
In my local repository all the files were there but index.js was missing since all files in any **/Output path would not be included.

Will never use global gitIgnore again.